# Android - Possible ways to determine the user speed

Tags: android, gps, location

I would like to ask you is there any possible ways to calculate the speed between two locations
for example if the user at location A and then move to location B , how to know the user speed between these two points ? 
Also , Can I determine if the user is walking or in car or train ... etc ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Read current location every 30 seconds or what ever interval you like.
2. Get different between the two locations and convert to miles using the following:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

1. Get the speed during that time by dividing with your time interval.

By the speed value, you can perhaps determine if the speed is walking (slowest), car or train (fastest).

Answer (score 1):

If your App is running you could either log the GPS Sensor data to check for the speed. Or just calculate the speed fromt the time the user needed to get from A to B.

Average speed for the whole way would be

```
average speed = distance between A and B / time needed to move from A to B
```

Comment: @JanuszHow to log the GPS Sensor to check for the speed ? Thanks

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question or search on stackoverflow for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/

to get speed of the user use this line of code:

```
speed = loc.getSpeed();
```

in onLocation change function.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to explain about How to get current speed of the User using GPS in Android Device By Using the Android Location Manager. Getting current speed can be used in many ways to the users.

**GPSManager.java**

```
public class GPSManager implements android.location.GpsStatus.Listener{
    private static final int gpsMinTime = 500;
    private static final int gpsMinDistance = 0;

    private static LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private static LocationListener locationListener = null;
    private static GPSCallback gpsCallback = null;
    Context mcontext;
    public GPSManager(Context context) {
       mcontext=context;
            GPSManager.locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                            if (GPSManager.gpsCallback != null) {
                                    GPSManager.gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) {
                    }
            };
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
               mcontext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
   }
    public GPSCallback getGPSCallback()
    {
            return GPSManager.gpsCallback;
    }

    public void setGPSCallback(final GPSCallback gpsCallback) {
            GPSManager.gpsCallback = gpsCallback;
    }

    public void startListening(final Context context) {
            if (GPSManager.locationManager == null) {
                    GPSManager.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }

            final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            final String bestProvider = GPSManager.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
        }
            if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0) {
                    GPSManager.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                                    GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, GPSManager.locationListener);
            }
            else {
                    final List<String> providers = GPSManager.locationManager.getProviders(true);
                    for (final String provider : providers)
                    {
                            GPSManager.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                                            GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, GPSManager.locationListener);
                    }
            }
    }
    public void stopListening() {
            try
            {
                    if (GPSManager.locationManager != null && GPSManager.locationListener != null) {
                            GPSManager.locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSManager.locationListener);
                    }
                    GPSManager.locationManager = null;
            }
            catch (final Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        int Satellites = 0;
        int SatellitesInFix = 0;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mcontext, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
        }
        int timetofix = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getTimeToFirstFix();
        Log.i("GPs", "Time to first fix = "+String.valueOf(timetofix));
        for (GpsSatellite sat : locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {
            if(sat.usedInFix()) {
                SatellitesInFix++;              
            }
            Satellites++;
        }
        Log.i("GPS", String.valueOf(Satellites) + " Used In Last Fix ("+SatellitesInFix+")"); 
    }
}
```

**GPSCallback.java**

```
public interface GPSCallback{
    public abstract void onGPSUpdate(Location location);
}
```

Comment: When linking to your own website, you **must explicitly state that it's your website**. See [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).